# google_maps_api.xml (debug) doesn't appear in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-bumblebee

I study Android Studio at last lesson Google Maps Activity for the tutorial. The tutorial videos work on Google_maps_api.xml for define api key but I doesn't even find the it at the Project android section.

[Tutorial Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuhWK.png)

[My Android Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HESF2.png)

Comment: I added some details about my problem. I hope It works.

Comment: Those are generated files, you don't need to bother about them at the moment. Does your app work correctly?

Comment: I guess the tutrial teach old genereated method or the google_maps_api.xml deprecated. I use new instruction but it still doesnt run without warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the steps of this document. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#api-key). I Only skiped to add it to project level **build-gradle**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
    }
}
```

Anymore It works

[Hello from Sydney :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1R4F.png)